# Create Azure board card when email received

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-boards

We are looking at using Azure boards to manage our workload. I am looking at workflow capabilities that you get in other similar tools like Jira. And want to know if it is possible to create a board item automatically when an email is received to a shared mailbox.

looks as though a flow is possible but you seem to need premium “Create an issue in Azure DevOps when an email is received” as we discussed earlier

https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?q=DEV+OPS

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation for the [Azure DevOps Services REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work), there doesn't seem to be an API for creating workitems.

You could use Azure [Logic Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/logic-apps/) which have integration with Office 365 and Azure DevOps:
[image: Azure DevOps: Create a work item]

You don't need a premium account, but you do need *an* account. There are some costs of course, you can find out more about the [Pricing model for Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-pricing).